# Is the theory of directed graphs complete?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, model-theory

Thinking about the theory of directed graphs *T* I came up to the thought that *T* may have no proper axioms. Thus, *T* is the first order predicate calculus with the signature consisting of a single predicate $P(x,y)$. This implies that *T* is complete. I don't understand how this could be true since *T* may have models satisfying opposite properties. Say, directed graphs may contain or not the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first-order theory with no non-logical axioms is never complete, no matter what the language you're looking at.  For instance, it does not decide the truth value of the sentence $\exists x\exists y~x \neq y$.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've confused it with the completeness in the sense that all theorems of *T* can be deduced within the axiomatic system.